# Yii Bootstrap not working, the grid is huge, the dropdowns don't drop, toggles fail to do so

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

The page has bootstrap skin but I'm not sure why some actions like showing the list on dropdown navbar, the loading option on button doesn't work either, the grid is huge, etc.

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'name project', 

    // preloading 'log' component
    'theme'=>'bootstrap',
    'preload'=>array('log', 'bootstrap'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(  
        'application.models.*', 
        'application.components.*',
        'ext.bootstrap-theme.widgets.*',
        'ext.bootstrap-theme.helpers.*',
        'ext.bootstrap-theme.behaviors.*',
    ),

    'language'=>'es',

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'swjskowk',
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'ext.bootstrap-theme.gii',
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                'gii'=>'gii',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),?>
```

I have a folder names bootstrap on themes, a bootstrap on extensions and bootstrap-theme on extensions again

Answer (score 0):

Fix components section

`'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),`

I think it should be

`bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),`

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are not loading the javascript that needs the boostrap in order to be able to show the dropdown list in the nav bar and so on.